# Does a photography need a patent?

Tags: patentability

I do not know to much about this domain. Bud if I want to register a photography made by mine, I need a patent for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copyright is what you are looking for. Patents are for inventions.

Comment: How can I obtain copyright for a photograph made by me?

Comment: I'm not an expert so you should do some Googling. I believe you automatically have a copyright. However you can register a copyright and gain some advantages.